# A general declaration for all inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

Consider, there is a class called `SuperClass` from which, `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` is derived. From each one of those derived Classes, there are further more two classes are derived each called `ChildClassAA` and `ChildClassAB`[AB stands for Bth Child class from the Ath Class.Lets not really pull our hair on this nomenclature].

Now, ideally, I want to declare a general type as a private member of another Class say `IndependentClass` which can be initialized during run time as either of the objects of type `ClassA`or `ClassB` or `ClassC` and even the derived classes like `ClassAA` or `ClassAB`.

Is there a possible way to do it?

Comment: A Superclass type can hold any instances of its subclasses. This is known as Polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, since all of these classes are derived (directly or indirectly) from `SuperClass`, you could just declare the field to be of type `SuperClass`.